# operations process in a computer

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture

Is it true that all high-level operations in a computer (say, copying, pasting, web surfing, running apps etc) are all finally converted to micro-operations (say, arithmetic, logical and shift) and then done?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Yeah, and from there into streams of electrons being shoved around tiny transistor arrays. It's not a simple process though, as you may imagine

Comment: Let me guide you to help me more. In my imagination, all the operations are converted to 1 and 0 then are stored into RAM. Then they are fetched to ALU (into CPU) then they should be stored somewhere like HDD. But I didn't understand the word "electrons". I would think those 0 and 1-s are stored inside some odd thing, flip-flop.